# Moving back nodes with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToBack = function() {
    return this.each(function() { 
        var firstChild = this.parentNode.firstChild; 
        if (firstChild) { 
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, firstChild); 
        } 
    }); 
};
```

this is the function for moving back the nodes, so:

```
node.enter().append("g").moveToBack();
```

if I use it this way it will work, but:

```
node.exit().select("g").moveToBack();
```

the `moveToBack` is undefined, the question is which object should I prototype to make it work for the `select("g")` ???

Comment: Both calls work for me. Can you provide a live demo which reproduces the effect?

Comment: My guess is that `node.exit()` contains the `g` nodes you want already and the `.select("g")` on that is empty because there are no nested `g` elements.